# why my player rotates in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, physics

I attach a movement script to the player. with reference to the roller ball tutorial and modified it for jump. the problem is that when may player moves in any direction the player starts to rotate in that direction and even if i am standing still at the one position it starts to rotate and fall down the platform. the player has a rigidbody, boxcollider components.

```
void Awake ()
{
    playerRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    Coll = GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>();
}

/*private void Update()
{

}*/
// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate ()
{
    float h = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    float v = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    bool down = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space);

    if (down)
    {
        playerRigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }

    Move(h, v);
}

private bool IsGrounded()
{

    return Physics.CheckCapsule(Coll.bounds.center, new Vector3(Coll.bounds.center.x,Coll.bounds.min.y,Coll.bounds.center.z),Coll.height * 9f,Ground);
}

void Move (float h, float v)
{
    movement.Set(h, 0f, v);
    movement = movement.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;

    playerRigidbody.MovePosition(transform.position + movement);
}
```

Comment: freeze rigidbody's rotation via inspector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code,you use AddForce function,so I confirm your player rigidbody doesn't set Kinematic to true.

When your charactor collision with any other objects ,such as ground,wall, your charactor maybe rotate.

You could freeze rigidbody's rotation via inspector like Bijan says.

I don't recommand your use AddForce and MovePosition together.It may has other problem.
[like this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1108127/addforce90-jump-while-moving-rigidbody-with-movepo.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the nature of the Rigidbody component. This component is very lifelike and when force is added and removed, the object still has inertia and therefore the object is still moving.

When it comes to the rotation it is due to the fact that when a force is applied to an object, the object also acquires rotational motion (also known as angular motion).

You can freeze the rotation using the constraints on the Rigidbody component. 
Have a deeper look into this component [here].[1](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html)

In my opinion, it is one of the core components of Unity and it is definitely worth looking into.

I hope I answered your question!

Comment: thank you sir i restrict the rotation in the inspector and it worked